# How to find the smallest linear function that's greater than all my datapoints?

Tags: curve-fitting

I want to find the least *`y = mx + b`* so that *`y > f(x)`*.

Basically, I've got the data in blue, and I want to find the function in red:

[image: my data and the end result]

Efficiency, rather than complete accuracy, is important. I've tried linear regression, but that gives a value that intersects the data.

Also, I'm using Java, but the problem should be general enough for this not to matter.

What would the function in red be called, and what would be an efficient way to compute it?

Comment: It might help if you could be more precise about the 'least line'. Suppose for example your data had a maximum in the middle. Then the horizontal line through the maximum would be above all your data, but you could rotate it a bit about the maximum and stil have a line above your data. Which of these would be the lowest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done e.g. with a method called "Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximation (COBYLA)". Scipy has a python wrapper of a FORTRAN implementation. You can specify an arbitrary number of constraint functions such as to force the fit to be always greater than the data.